Sending photos to the server using Photo Picker
There is a script for sending an image to the server. I need to change the photo picker to Photo Picker, i.e. use PickVisualMediaRequest, since soon it will not be possible to use the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES resolution if the main function of the application is not working with images. How can this be implemented? Any ideas? Thank you.
Here is the code
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // For Android 5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Make sure there is no existing callback
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            // Open file chooser intent
            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Load your desired URL
    webView.loadUrl("https://site.html");
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri[] result = null;
            // Check if the response is positive
            if (data != null) {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    result = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        }
    }
}

}

"How can this be implemented?" -- how can what be implemented?

fileChooserParams.createIntent(); What is fileChooserParams ? And what kind of intent is returned by .createIntent();,? We dont know what you do.

Use PickVisualMediaRequest instead Intent
